# overlap when using css3 transform, any way to prevent this

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, transform

Here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/WLJUC/

notice how when you click to rotate the larger container overlaps the smaller one.

this is problematic because im trying to create a picture gallery of sorts where you can click to rotate and enlarge images.  this wouldnt be a problem but some images are very long and skinny.  I'd prefer if the rotated div were to push down the div below it, and not overlap.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the blue should never touch the red. Here's an example of using margin to drop the blue guy: http://jsfiddle.net/WLJUC/27/

I don't know the details of you photos to get the example perfect, but in general you can check via JS the rotation, and then use a margin on the blue div to bump it down a certain amount. (Threw in some transition just to visualize it a bit better)

*(Old, useless answer) You have a tag for z-index, yet you didn't use it in your example. Applying position relative to both, z-index: 0 to the red one and z-index: 1 to the blue will stop the overlap from my quick test: http://jsfiddle.net/WLJUC/10/*

Comment: This doesn't help, because his image(this is an image gallery) will now be hidden behind something. I think he wants the blue section to always be below the pink section, never touching each other.

Comment: this is pretty good except seems buggy when you click on it a few times?  have you tried that.  after a few times clicking it goes back to old behavior.  I will give you correct answer for effort

Comment: You are correct. Since you were adding 90 constantly, I didn't take into account that it wouldn't always be 90/270 degrees. I added an extra line to reset the count at 360.